# How to get classloader for a bundle in equinox?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, classloader, bundle, equinox

I have read a lot of equinox code for this, but still can't figure out a non-hacky way of getting the classloader for a osgi bundle in eclipse equinox setup. Is there one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer (certainly for OSGi 4.1, not sure of 4.2) is you can't get a bundle's classloader.  However the `Bundle` interface exposes a `loadClass()` method and this would allow you to write a classloader that wraps the bundle API and delegates to that `loadClass()` method.  Or you can save some time and use Spring DM's `BundleDelegatingClassLoader` class instead.

Answer (score 40):

In OSGi 4.3 you can use:

```
bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class).getClassLoader()
```

Answer (score 6):

The class loader of a bundle can be obtained through the BundleWiring interface. Here a short example:

```
Bundle bundle = bundleContext.getBundle();
BundleWiring bundleWiring = bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class);
ClassLoader classLoader = bundleWiring.getClassLoader();
```

Answer (score 2):

In normal java code, you can get the class loader that loaded a given object with

```
object.getClass().getClassLoader();
```

Or even just

```
SomeType.class.getClassLoader();
```

The same applies to Equinox, just use an object or type that comes from the bundle you are interested in.

Comment: But then you have a bootstrapping problem. How do you get that first instance?

Comment: If you have dependency on the other bundle, you can refer to the other class directly (SomeType.class) the osgi classloaders delegate between bundles so it still comes from the other classloader.  If you don't have a dependency you need to get the Bundle object (using PackageAdmin) and use Bundle#loadClass as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: J2SE class loading does not fit for J2EE. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34787419/pmd-rule-use-proper-class-loader-explaination

Comment: This would not be the correct class loader.  The class loader which was used to load the Bundle class generally will not be the same thing as the bundle acting as a class loader.  A little more generally, the class loader of ClassLoader.class will generally not be the same as any given class loader instance.  While in simple environments, these may turn out to be the same, in partitioned environments (OSGi, JavaEE) they will be different.