# PMD rule "Use Proper Class Loader" explaination?

Tags: java, classloader, pmd

There is the following PMD rule:

> Use Proper Class Loader (Critical)
>
> In J2EE `getClassLoader()` might not work as expected. Use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` instead.

Can somewhat explain more what they are thinking of? What exactly means "J2EE" environment here?

Answer (score 1):

J2EE environment refers to the Java Enterprise Edition. Here, you do not run your program as a standalone application on the JVM, but instead, you let the JEE Application Server (e.g. Glassfish or Tomcat) to run it for you.

Application Servers provide a lot of different ways to run your program, for example they offer concurrent and distributed execution. AppServers play with classloaders, sometimes there is a hierarchy, for example the EAR (Enterprise ARchive) has one, and a WAR (Web ARchive) inside the EAR has a different one. Because of this it is not ensured you will always get the right ClassLoader with a `getClassLoader()` call. With `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` you will always get the ClassLoader that loaded your app.

(Note: This is not entirely true, some applications make trick with ContextClassLoader (like Spring, OSGi). Still, this is the best way to get your proper ClassLoader).

Comment: "get the right ClassLoader" - this part is unclear. if I say: `ref.getClass().getClassLoader()`, i should get the class loader that loaded this class, right? How this can be changed? I am not talking about the classloader that loaded my app; as my class may be loaded by different classloader.

Comment: Maybe this post clarifies it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771679/difference-between-threads-context-class-loader-and-normal-classloader

Comment: Hm, i do understand the difference, maybe I need to clarify myself. If I do `ref.getClass().getClassLoader()` - i should always get the class loader that loaded class of `ref`. And this can not change, right? This may or may not be the same as context CL, but that is on me to handle if I need. Sometimes I want this, sometimes i don't. So I am puzzled why PMD would warn about this anyway - it sounds as a rule that you should use in jee environment - and wonder if there is something more that i dont see.