# Resource loading using ClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader

I have a resource file I need to load at runtime...it is in `src/main/resources`

I have successfully loaded the file to an inputStream using :

```
LoadSAC.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("someFile.txt");
```

`LoadSAC` is the class name ...

However, PMD complains about this suggests I use

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(...)
```

I have tried numerous combinations and can never get the file to be located... Any thoughts... I have trolled a number of searches with plenty of suggestions but none seem to work...

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PMD rule "Use Proper Class Loader" explaination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34787419/pmd-rule-use-proper-class-loader-explaination)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `someFile.txt` is in the same folder than `LoadSAC.java`, you can do:

```
InputStream is = LoadSAC.class.getResourceAsStream("someFile.txt");
```

If `someFile.txt` is in a subfolder `subdir`, you can do:

```
InputStream is = LoadSAC.class.getResourceAsStream("subdir/someFile.txt");
```

If your method in `LoadSAC.java` is non-static, you can replace `LoadSAC.class.getResourceAsStream...` by `getClass().getResourceAsStream...`

Be careful when compiling with `ant` or `maven`, by default, only `.java` file are copied as `.class` files in the build directory.

You have to write some rules to include `someFile.txt` in the final `jar`.

In your `resource` directory, you can add a little helper class like this:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.URLDataSource;

public abstract class ResourceHelper {

    public static URL getURL(String name) {
        return ResourceHelper.class.getResource(name);
    }

    public static InputStream getInputStream(String name) {
        return ResourceHelper.class.getResourceAsStream(name);
    }

    public static DataSource getDataSource(String name) {
        return new URLDataSource(getURL(name));
    }
}
```

In `LoadSAC.java` just call:

```
InputStream is = ResourceHelper.getInputStream("someFile.txt");
```

Comment: Yes ...the file I need is in the src/main/resources folder ...it is not co-located with the LoadSAC class ...the method is NON STATIC

Comment: I have completed my response to show you a simple way to find a resource. Hope it's help you.

Comment: You can remove the method `getDataSource` (and the 2 imports `javax.activation.*`), I use this with Javamail api.

Comment: Perfect ...Thank you !

Comment: `"If someFile.txt is in the same folder than LoadSAC.java..."` -- no, not true. This should read, `"If someFile.txt is in the same folder than LoadSAC.class..."`. The class loader looks in the location of the `.class` files and doesn't care a whit for where the `.java` files are located, or any files held with the `.java` files. That's why it is called a "class" loader.