# dynamic loading of package-plugin eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dynamic, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plugin in eclipse, which is a metrics view that will show a list of syntactic metrics(of Xtext files). the plugin is written in java, as a plugin project in eclipse.

How can I load dynamically from the Activator (the file that created in eclipse plugin project) all classes from a certain package,directly to the metric table I prepare.

I searched about it and didn't find any guides or useful information to help me with this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific about where you got stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Basically eclipse plugins are osgi bundles. Since each osgi bundle (i.e. eclipse plugin) has a own classloader try using that class loader to resolve related resources.

See [How to get classloader for a bundle in equinox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503304/how-to-get-classloader-for-a-bundle-in-equinox)