# ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() vs obj.getClass().getClassLoader().getSystemClassLoader()

Tags: java, classloader

Are these exactly same:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() // 1
```

vs:

```
obj.getClass().getClassLoader().getSystemClassLoader() // 2
Person.class.getClassLoader().getSystemClassLoader()
```

**Is there a situation possible where they could yield different results?**

Answer (score 3):

As per [`ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader()) this is normally  the class loader used to start the application. The `java.system.class.loader` property can be used to override the returned class loader, however:

> The system property to override the system class loader is not examined until the VM is almost fully initialized. Code that executes this method during startup should take care not to cache the return value until the system is fully initialized.

In more complex setups `obj.getClass().getClassLoader()` or `Person.class.getClassLoader()` can return a custom class loader e.g. [OSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi). It's entirely up to this custom class loader to return the system class loader. It 
might choose not e.g. because it would bypass the OSGI boundle class loading boundaries, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1504050/1602555).

So most of the time they should be the same, but nothing stops you from configuring the JVM or writing software that would make them different.

Comment: For example, classloaders will be different for the Spring Boot application, if you run repackaged jar. Spring Boot uses LaunchedURLClassLoader. SystemClassLoader doesn't know about new classes location inside the repackaged jar file thus it cannot load any resources from resources folder.