# Fail to load class using ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm trying to load some java built-in classes like Object and Calendar

```
Class<?> proxied = new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(Calendar.class)
                .method(ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isClone().or(ElementMatchers.isFinalizer()).or(ElementMatchers.isEquals()).or(ElementMatchers.isHashCode()).or(ElementMatchers.isToString())))
                .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new MyMethodInterceptor()))
                .make()
                .load(Calendar.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
                .getLoaded();
```

When using `Calendar.class.getClassLoader()`, it will fail.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader.findClass(ByteArrayClassLoader.java:403)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
... 15 more
```

However, if I change the classLoader to `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` it works good.
Here's a post I found [SystemClassLoader vs obj.getClass.getClassLoader()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54037306/classloader-getsystemclassloader-vs-obj-getclass-getclassloader-getsystemc).
Can someone help explain the reason behind it?

Comment: _"it will fail"_ - What is the error message (complete stack trace)?  Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 0):

The `getClassLoader()` method of `java.lang.Class` is specced to return `null` when that class was loaded by the system classloader. Why doesn't it return the ClassLoader instance representing the system loader? I'm sure there's a reason for it, but I'm not familiar with it. At any rate, that's how it works. (This also explains why it's `MyClass.class.getResource` and never `MyClass.class.getClassLoader.getResource`).